# What is `using namespace std;`, and why do I need it to compile programs with recent C++ compilers?

Tags: c++

What is `using namespace std;` in recent C++?

In old compilers such as Turbo C++, this appears to be unsupported as it causes a compiler error. In more recent C++ compilers, this is the only method for compiling and running the program.

Comment: It is [something that should be avoided](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: What you call "recent" is 15 years old, and what you call "old" is truly ancient and best forgotten

Comment: Please use more descriptive title in the future, and if possible spend some more time writing it to correct simple errors and typos.

Comment: _In more recent C++ compilers, this is the only method for compiling and running the program._ -- No, it isn't. Prepending `std::` to items that live in that namespace is another method for compiling your program (at least, in any compiler you want to be using).

Comment: If u can tell me the better compilers for C++..for old programs...without "using namespace.std;"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++ uses "namespaces" to group related classes and functions.  The C++ Standard Library is almost entirely defined inside a namespace called `std` (short for "standard").  When you `#include` a standard header such as `<string>` it contains definitions like this:

```
namespace std
{
  template<typename T>
    class allocator;

  template<typename Ch>
    class char_traits
    {
       // ...
    };

  template<typename Ch, typename Traits = char_traits<Ch>, typename Alloc = allcoator<Ch>>
    class basic_string
    {
       // ...
    };

  typedef basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> > string;
}
```

The names `allocator`, `char_traits`, `basic_string` and `string` are all declared in namespace `std`, so after including that header you need to refer to them as `std::string` etc.

Alternatively, you can use a *using-directive* such as `using namespace std` which makes all the names from namespace `std` available in the current scope, so following the using-directive you can just say `string` instead of `std::string`.

The ancient TurboC++ compiler does not follow the standard, so its standard library just puts names in the global namespace, so you have to refer to `string` not `std::string` and you can't use using-directives.  The first C++ standard was published in 1998, so you should not be using pre-standard compilers in 2013, it will not be a valuable education.

Answer (score 6):

Turbo C++ is a 20+ year old compiler. You shouldn't be using it.

That said,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

in a modern compiler is the same as writing the following in Turbo C for the standard headers.

```
#include <iostream.h>
```

Turbo C++ is pre-namespaces. So all standard headers are not in `namespace std`. So you don't need the using `namespace std`.

You will never need `using namespace std` in Turbo C++ because it doesn't support namespaces. Turbo C++ doesn't support probably 50% of C++ stuff - it's that old. Use Visual C++ (Express editions are free) or G++ for C++.

Comment: thank you very much @user93353 but in our college faculty saying that Turbo is the best one for basic compiling..thats okay but while searching programs in the internet i am getting new ones only..those programs are not working in Turbo c++. What is the alternate?

Comment: See http://isocpp.org/get-started for some freely-available modern compilers

Comment: You need to find a new college. You're obviously not going to get taught real C++.

Comment: Thanks but now its not possible to change the college...if u can tell me the better compilers for C++..for old programs...without "using namespace.std;"

Comment: There's no point in learning obsolete C++. If you want to learn basics, look into Assembler and/or C - if you want to learn proper C++, get a modern compiler.

Answer (score 2):

`using namespace std;` tells the compiler that you don't care about the carefully designed use of `std` in the standard library, but would rather deal with unpredictable and sometimes disastrous name conflicts on your own.

Don't use it. It is **never** necessary, even though some IDEs insert it automatically. If you have one of those, delete the declaration whenever it occurs.

To use names from the standard library, qualify then with `std::`. Like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, world\n";
}
```

Comment: "even though some IDEs insert it automatically." - which IDEs would that be?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld I have seen Eclipse do it. So does ideone.com.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld - I don't know; a couple of times when I've suggested not using it, I've gotten a reply that it gets inserted automatically.